# ASP.Net MVC Routing problem with jQuery AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

My page is domain.com/home/details/1

In my jQuery AJAX call I have the following however when it makes that call its making a call to domain.com/home/details/home/getdata

What can I do to get it to resolve properly?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "bServerSide": true,
                "sAjaxSource": "Home/GetData/",
                "bProcessing": true,
                "bPaginate": true,
                "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
                "bFilter": true,
                "bAutoWidth": false,
                "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                    /* Add some extra data to the sender */
                    //aoData.push({ "filtervalue": $('#filtervalue').val(), "Options": $('#Options').val() });
                    $.getJSON(sSource, aoData.concat($('form').serializeArray()), function (json) {
                        /* Do whatever additional processing you want on the callback, then tell DataTables */
                        fnCallback(json)
                    });
                }
            });

        });
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Absolutely **always** use URL helpers when dealing with urls in ASP.NET MVC. Absolutely **never** hardcode urls as you did.

So:

```
"sAjaxSource": "@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")"
```

and if this is in a separate javascript file, you could use HTML5 `data-*` attributes on the `#example`:

```
<div id="example" data-url="@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")">
    ...
</div>
```

and then in your separate js you could use the [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
"sAjaxSource": $('#example').data('url')
```

Comment: +1 for suggesting helpers. If you're deploying your app within a virtual directory (e.g http://domain.com/myapp/), using `/Home/GetData` won't work.

Comment: Good advice on suggestions to always use URL helpers and never hardcode urls.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try puting a leading slash before the Ajax Source?

```
"sAjaxSource": "/Home/GetData/"
```

**UPDATE**

As stated in the comments below, hardcoding the URL could cause problems later down the line.

Darin has already posted about using the built in URL helpers so I wont edit my post to include that info. I do it a slightly different way as documented here:

[Create Extension methods of UrlHelper to generate your url from Route](http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/01/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-1.aspx)

I've found this way of working to be extremely helpful when working with a front end team. They found it really easy to understand the `Url.RequestedPage()` format and it meant they didn't need my help everytime they wanted to link or request something.

Comment: God damn it. I thought I tried every scenario obviosuly not that one! Thanks

Comment: -1, for hardcoding urls instead of using Url heleprs. This will break as soon as you deploy your application in a virtual directory inside IIS.

Comment: What @Darin said is right, although it worked for you now, it'll break in the future, use permanent healthy solutions.

Comment: Fair call Darin. I agree that using a hardcoded URL isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I think your path should be

```
"sAjaxSource": "/home/details/home/getdata",
```

and shouldn't `getdata` be a filename like getdata.php or something

```
"sAjaxSource": "/home/details/home/getdata.php",
```